# Polymer 2.x: dom-repeat does not observe changes to computed array's children

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-2.x

I have a `dom-repeat` and another `dom-repeat` nested inside it.  The outer one is bound to  a computed array.  When I make changes to the parent array, the changes are observed (meaning the observer code is fired), but the changes are not reflected in the UI/`dom-repeat`.

Here is example of my code.  Clicking on the `div` inside the second `dom-repeat` triggers function `handleItemTap`, which then makes a change to the parent array.  This change is then observed, and the computed array is recomputed; however, adding `IsChecked` to the parent object does not affect the checkbox in the UI, which is supposed to be bound to the `IsChecked` property.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<template is="dom-repeat"
          items="[[outerComputedArray]]" as="group"
          id="groupRepeater">
    <div class="group-container">       
        <template is="dom-repeat"
                  items="[[group.InnerArray]]" as="sesh">
            <div on-tap="handleItemTap">
                <paper-checkbox id="paperCheckboxId"
                                checked="[[sesh.IsChecked]]"></paper-checkbox>
            </div>
        </template>
    </div>
</template>

...

static get properties() {
    return {
        'parentArray': Array,
        'outerComputedArray': {
            type: Array,
            computed: 'computeOuterArray(parentArray.*)'
        }
    }
}

computeOuterArray(parentArray) {
    if (!(typeof parentArray.base === 'undefined' || parentArray.base == null || parentArray.base.length == 0)) {
        let groupedGrid = parentArray.base.reduce((a, b) => {
            a = a || [];
            let idx = a.findIndex(x => x.PaymentType == b.PaymentType);
            if (idx == -1) {
                let newArray = [];
                newArray.push(b);
                a.push({ 'PaymentType': b.PaymentType, 'InnerArray': newArray });
            }
            else {
                a[idx].InnerArray.push(b);
            }
            return a;
        }, []).map(x => {
            x.Total = x.InnerArray.map(y => y.TotalAmount).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
            return x;
        });
        groupedGrid.sort((a, b) => a.PaymentType.localeCompare(b.PaymentType));

        return groupedGrid;
    }

    return [];
}

handleItemTap(e) {
    let idx = this.parentArray.findIndex(x => x.id == e.model.sesh.id);
    this.set(`parentArray.${idx}.IsChecked`, !(!!e.model.sesh.IsChecked));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really appreciate @mary-shaw trying to help out, but I wasn't able to get those suggestions working.  Here's what I've come up with for now.  I've put an observer on `outerComputedArray` that updates a second array--a new property called `selectedIds`--with any items for which the property `IsChecked` has been changed.  I've then added another computing function that checks if `selectedIds` has the same `id` property as the object in the innermost `dom-repeat`.

```
<template is="dom-repeat"
          items="[[outerComputedArray]]" as="group">
    <div class="group-container">       
        <template is="dom-repeat"
                  items="[[group.InnerArray]]" as="sesh">
            <div on-tap="handleItemTap">
                <paper-checkbox id="paperCheckboxId"
                                checked="[[computeIsChecked(selectedIds.*, sesh.id)]]"></paper-checkbox>
            </div>
        </template>
    </div>
</template>

...
<script>
    static get properties() {
        return {
            'parentArray': Array,
            'outerComputedArray': {
                type: Array,
                computed: 'computeOuterArray(parentArray.*)'
            },
            'selectedIds': Array
        }
    }

    static get observers() {
        return [
            'onOuterComputedArrayChanged(outerComputedArray.*)'
        ]
    }

    onOuterComputedArrayChanged(outerComputedArray) {
        if (!(typeof outerComputedArray.base === 'undefined' || outerComputedArray.base == null || outerComputedArray.base.length == 0)) {
            this.set('selectedIds', outerComputedArray.base.filter(x => x.InnerArray.some(y => !!y.IsChecked)).map(x => x.InnerArray.filter(y => !!y.IsChecked)).reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []).map(x => x.id));
        }
    }

    computeIsChecked(selectedIds, id) {
        if (!(typeof selectedIds.base === 'undefined' || selectedIds.base == null || selectedIds.base.length == 0)) {
            return selectedIds.base.some(x => x == id);
        }

        return !!0;
    }

    computeOuterArray(parentArray) {
        if (!(typeof parentArray.base === 'undefined' || parentArray.base == null || parentArray.base.length == 0)) {
            let groupedGrid = parentArray.base.reduce((a, b) => {
                a = a || [];
                let idx = a.findIndex(x => x.PaymentType == b.PaymentType);
                if (idx == -1) {
                    let newArray = [];
                    newArray.push(b);
                    a.push({ 'PaymentType': b.PaymentType, 'InnerArray': newArray });
                }
                else {
                    a[idx].InnerArray.push(b);
                }
                return a;
            }, []).map(x => {
                x.Total = x.InnerArray.map(y => y.TotalAmount).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
                return x;
            });
            groupedGrid.sort((a, b) => a.PaymentType.localeCompare(b.PaymentType));

            return groupedGrid;
        }

        return [];
    }

    handleItemTap(e) {
        let idx = this.parentArray.findIndex(x => x.id == e.model.sesh.id);
        this.set(`parentArray.${idx}.IsChecked`, !(!!e.model.sesh.IsChecked));
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Polymer object dirty-checking is the problem here. It is used to speed up Polymer, but sometimes dirty-checking doesn't work (for example, when you change elements in an array).
To get around it, you need to use the [mutable data mixin](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/data-system#mutable-data).

First, you need to bring in the mixin when you declare your element.

`class MyMutableElement extends Polymer.MutableData(Polymer.Element) { ... }`

You also need to add the mutable-data flag to your dom-repeat.

`<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[outerComputedArray]]" as="group" id="groupRepeater" mutable-data>`

If it still doesn't work, try adding something like this to the end of your computeOuterArray function, as well (but only if you actually change the array).

`timeout(() => { this.notifyPath('outerComputedArray') }, 10)`

Comment: For sure? The `computeOuterArray` method gets called every time, so in that sense I'd think the dirty-checking is working OK. If it weren't, `computeOuterArray` would never get hit the second time, correct? Please forgive me if I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: `computeOuterArray` is called when `parentArray` changes.  That doesn't mean Polymer knows that `outerComputedArray` has changed.

Comment: Another way to fix it would be to create a completely new variable for `outerComputedArray` every time.

Comment: "computeOuterArray is called when parentArray changes. That doesn't mean Polymer knows that outerComputedArray has changed." If I set an observer on `outerComputedArray` it observes the change. Would that still happen if `notifyPath` weren't working?

Comment: I tried adding the `MutableData` mixin and adding `mutable-data` to my `dom-repeat` but I am getting the exact same behavior as before.

Comment: Hmm.  When I use computed arrays in a template, I call the computing function within the template rather than declaring it as a property.  It works really well to use it that way.  `<template is="dom-repeat"
          items="[[computeOuterArray(parentArray)]]" as="group"
          id="groupRepeater">`

Comment: I tried to use the computing function instead of the computed property, and that likewise didn't work. I've filed a bug [here](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/5127) and found a hacky workaround for now.